# Ubuntu freezes without acpi=off

Tags: 18.04, 19.10, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu alongside with windows (dualboot) and it's "working fine so far".
But when I start Ubuntu without acpi=off it keeps freezing (so I have no choise but pressing the reset button on my pc)

I've also tried to start Ubuntu with acpi=ht and acpi=strict, but both of them also lead to freezes.
Please note: my PC doesn't freeze immediately (well sometimes it does, but not all the time), just when clicking on an url in a webbrowser, opening Spotify or using the terminal (also on other occurances.. in general it just freezes randomly over and over again).
Also some programs, like Firefox or Google Chrome, crash randomly. Again: not if I set acpi=off.

I have also tried to set processor.cstate=1 but it didn't help me either.

Please let me know if you need some log file or additional informations (but please let me know how to get them / where to find them)
btw. W10 is running without any problems at all.

Specs:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3700X
GPU: AMD Vega56
RAM: 32GB 2666mhz
Mainboard: Asus ROG Strix X370-F

BIOS version: 5220

`~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G         12G         15G        508M        3,4G         18G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G`

`~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60`

Any ideas?

I would really appreciate some help.

Edit:
I've tried using a new 19.10 LTS installation and today I've also tried 20.04 LTS without any success.

Comment: Show me the results of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Bios version is: `5220`.
What do you mean with make/model #? Where can I find these informations? I bought those parts a while ago and put the pc together by myself. 
(I tried `dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'` but it just returned: 
`System Information
 Manufacturer: System manufacturer
 Product Name: System Product Name
 Version: System Version`

Comment: I checked for a newer BIOS for your Asus ROG Strix X370-F, and you have the current BIOS already. Good! Is your CPU/RAM overclocked? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Done. No, I am not overclocking anything at all. (btw. the high memory usage in `free -h`is because I am running memtest right now (no errors so far).

Comment: Perfect. I was going to suggest memtest next. Make sure to get 4/4 passes.

Comment: No errors so far... do you have any other ideas in meanwhile? I really doubt that it's cause of the memory. I tested it like two weeks ago and it was totally fine (and I would assume that Windows 10 would have problems as well if it would be cause of the RAM).

Comment: Not unless there's some Ryzen 3700X-specific fix. Sorry.

Comment: The funny thing is that I am running it since a few hours (since I started memetest) without acpi=off. And it didn't crash/freeze or something like that. But I am using like all cores. Its like it freezes without any high CPU usage

Comment: I would Google "Ryzen 3700X Ubuntu freeze".

Comment: Try GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash idle=nomwait"

Comment: See https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=2

Comment: Looks like this one https://bugs.launchpad.net/amd/+bug/1776563 Something AMD related TL;DR: Just install 19.10

Comment: Hey, I have tried idle=nomwait, without any success. After that I tried Ubuntu 19.10 -> still freezes / random programm crashes. Today I have also tried 20.04, unfortunately it crashed again. I have no idea what I should do..